# MYSQL medium query optimization with subqueries

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have this query that returns the following:

- Region name
- Region ID
- RANK (Position) of this Region, based on the total number of votes
- Nb of distinct users from this region
- Nb of distinct photos from this region

The query take about ~7.5s to complete... I'd like some advice to optimize my query.

```
            select
            WrappedQuery.*,
            regions.name as region_name,
            regions.id as region_id,
            count(distinct users.id) as nb_users,
            count(distinct photos.id) as nb_photos
            from (
                select
                  @rownum := @rownum +1 as rank,
                  prequery.region_id,
                  prequery.VoteCount
                from
                  ( select @rownum := 0 ) sqlvars,
                  ( select region_id, count(id) VoteCount
                      from votes
                      where theme_id = '{$currentTheme}'
                      group by region_id
                      order by count(id) desc ) prequery
              ) WrappedQuery, regions, users, photos
              WHERE regions.id = WrappedQuery.region_id
              AND users.region_id = WrappedQuery.region_id
              AND photos.region_id = WrappedQuery.region_id
              GROUP BY WrappedQuery.region_id
              ORDER BY WrappedQuery.rank ASC
              LIMIT 0, 1
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has way too much overhead for what you want to achieve. I've rewritten it for you...

```
select 
/*you don't need that
@rownum := @rownum +1 as rank, 
*/
regions.name as region_name,
regions.id as region_id,
count(distinct users.id) as nb_users,
count(distinct photos.id) as nb_photos,
count(votes.id) as VoteCount
from votes
INNER JOIN regions ON votes.region_id = regions.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.region_id = regions.id
INNER JOIN photos ON photos.region_id = regions.id
/*you don't need that
, ( select @rownum := 0 ) sqlvars
*/
where theme_id = '{$currentTheme}'
group by regions.id
order by VoteCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I commented out the part with the rank, since you just want 1 row anyway.

If it still is too slow, you have to post the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT .../*the query from above*/`, so we can see if an index is used. Also post the table creation scripts (with `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName`). Either this, or you try to create missing indexes yourself.

**UPDATE:**

Rewritten your query again, might be faster this way:

```
select
WrappedQuery.*,
regions.name as region_name,
regions.id as region_id,
count(distinct users.id) as nb_users,
count(distinct photos.id) as nb_photos
from (
       select region_id, count(id) VoteCount
          from votes
          where theme_id = '{$currentTheme}'
          group by region_id
          ORDER BY VoteCount DESC
          LIMIT 1
  ) WrappedQuery, regions, users, photos
  WHERE regions.id = WrappedQuery.region_id
  AND users.region_id = WrappedQuery.region_id
  AND photos.region_id = WrappedQuery.region_id
  GROUP BY WrappedQuery.region_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your query but after ~40s of execution I got a MySQL error (#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3295_0.MYI'; try to repair it.) I guess the query is just too long. Here is a screenshot of the EXPLAIN SELECT[...]. I didn't know I could do that. http://sht.tl/ryLE All the indexes should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to find informations about that. I also re-executed the EXPLAIN query and the result is different: http://sht.tl/P0I8U

Comment: The result is different because my first EXPLAIN was incorrect. Sorry about that.

Comment: In your explain there are derived select types, which means subqueries. There are no more subqueries in the query I posted.

Comment: Yep but the query you posted fills the tmp folder which is 2gb and give a MySQL error  (#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3295_0.MYI'; try to repair it.)

Comment: @Kev Updated answer again.

Comment: The updated query works very well! Took 0.3s instead of 3.5s !

Comment: Ok I still have an issue. The query works great for this exact case, as I only need the " TOP " ranked region. But what if there is no LIMIT 1 and I want every region with their rank, as the query did before? The complete query (without the limit) that gets all the region is http://paste.laravel.com/npA This is the major point here: I need the rank of every regions based on their votes.

Comment: I should have removed the LIMIT 1 in my first post.

Comment: Then your original query is actually just fine. You'll have to solve the issue by adjusting indexes then.

Comment: Ok thanks. Your query was still useful in the homepage to show the first position :-)